# How to display file's download link in list?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm using FileField module. I have created:

1. A Content Part "Document list item" which contain File Field
2. A Content Type "File Item" which contain "Document list item" + Common + Title + Containable
3. A list which contain "File Item"

Also I've chaged Placement file by adding:

```
<Match ContentType="FileItem">
    <Match DisplayType="Summary">
            <Place  Parts_Common_Metadata_Summary="Nowhere"/>
        </Match>
    </Match>
```

So now I see the list of titles. When I click title, on the details page there is a link to download.
But how to display download link in Summary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So problem is solved:

I've added **Fields_Contrib_File** to the Placement file:

```
    <Match ContentType="FileItem">
        <Match DisplayType="Summary">
                <Place  Parts_Common_Metadata_Summary="Nowhere" Fields_Contrib_File="Content" Parts_Title_Summary="Nowhere"/>
            </Match>
        </Match>
```

I've removed display name from the template file ~/Modules/Contrib.FileField/Views/Fields/**Contrib.File.cshtml**:

```
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;

@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ContentField.Path)) 
{
   <p class="file-field">       
      <a href="@Url.Content(Model.ContentField.Path)" target="@Model.Settings.OpenAction">@Model.ContentField.Text</a>
   </p> 
}
```